# Remove unnecessary elements from insert link menu: TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I use TinyMCE for content editing. I allow people to enter links in their HTML. So when the user clicks on add link, he sees the following popup:

[image]

But none of the users is actually using any of the fields except of `URL`. Is there a way to remove all these fields and leave only `URL`, but when the user click on the link in created html - to open this link in the new tab/window?

I tried to look at their documentation, but was not able to find how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can clone the tinymce core plugin rename it and remove the parts you don't need.
Don't forget to include the new name in your tinymce plugin and button config.